# Return sum of data from Column A and corresponding Name from column B using SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

This is a bit tricky situation. I'm using the T-SQL language.

My current data in SQL Server is: there are seminars and multiple BDMs under each seminar who can book multiple opportunities.

I need the total of "Oppty Booked" per seminar but only the name of BDM who has made the highest booking.

[This the current data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afQ4z.png)

```
Seminar BDM Name    Oppty Booked
--------------------------------
Broome  Ian         6
Broome  Nas         5
Broome  Kit         4
Broome  Fred        0
Gympie  Sam         16
Gympie  Amanda      2
Gympie  Lidcombe    4
```

What I need is: [Required Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Y5CO.png)

```
Seminar BDM Name    Oppty Booked
--------------------------------
Broome  Ian         15
Gympie  Sam         22
```

What can I do to get this?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps another option

**Example**

```
Select Top 1 with ties 
       Seminar
      ,[BDM Name]
      ,[Oppty Booked] = sum([Oppty Booked]) over (Partition By Seminar)
 From  YourTable
 Order By Row_Number() over (Partition By Seminar Order By [Oppty Booked] desc)
```

**Returns**

```
Seminar BDM Name    Oppty Booked
Broome  Ian         15
Gympie  Sam         22
```

Comment: Thanks John! I love your answer, it's very simple and straight forward.

Comment: @Pal1989 Yup.  That's me.  I'm a simple guy.  Food, shelter, and High Speed Internet Access.   Happy it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use below query.  Read about [RANK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rank-transact-sql).

```
CREATE TABLE #Test
(
Seminar VARCHAR(100),
BDM_Name VARCHAR(100),
Oppty_Booked int
)

insert into #TEst values 
('Broome', 'Ian',6)
,('Broome', 'Nas',5)
,('Broome', 'Kit',4)
,('Broome', 'Fred',0)
,('Gympie', 'Sam',16)
,('Gympie', 'Amanda',2)
,('Gympie', 'Lidcombe',4)

select * from #Test

select  Seminar, BDM_Name, Oppty_Booked
from 
(
select 
Seminar,
BDM_Name,
Rank() OVER (partition by Seminar order by Oppty_Booked desc) as RN,
SUM(Oppty_Booked)OVER (partition by Seminar )  as Oppty_Booked
from #Test
) t
where t.rn=1
```

Comment: You are a genius, thanks for the answer. It really helped!